# selecting HTML from a document using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get a HTML selection out of the document.

Say, I have `<u>Hi <i>I am <b>TOM</b></i></u>` displayed.

I want to select `am TO`.

The following JS

```
var span = document.createElement( 'SPAN' );
span.appendChild( window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents() );
span.innerHTML;
```

only displays `am <b>TO</b>`. Rest of the tags which have influence on the selection are lost.

Is there any way to get these lost tags under selection too?

Thanks :)

Comment: By lost tags, you mean that the expected output should have been `<u><i>am <b>TO</b></i></u>`?

Comment: Whats the purpose of maintaining the html integrity? Perhaps this will help come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: @mads.ohm yes. I am expecting the output you gave as example.

Comment: @alvincrespo I am writing this JS to get a HTML selection from an editor( in an email client ) to which user can reply, i.e. reply-to-only-selected-text. So this integrity is needed. It would be not good if user was replying to underline-italics-bold, but when he replied, he only saw bold as quoted message in reply message.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply append the opening tags before the `window.getSelection` and append the closing tags after it **if** this is a specific problem (as opposed to a general problem in which you cannot anticipate the tags used) .

Comment: So, that means we manually need to scan all the contents and prepend/append tags?